# Mysql query Update not add values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update mysql records there are code above. But i take error. What can i do
This is my listed mysql info
sayfa.php

```
while ($veri = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu1)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$veri['id']}</td>
            <td>{$veri['isim']}</td>
            <td>{$veri['durum']}</td>
            <td>{$veri['sira']}</td>
            <td>{$veri['seo_baslik']}</td>
            <td>{$veri['seo_aciklama']}</td>
            <th><a href=\"sil.php?id={$veri['id']}&sil=1\" onclik=\"return confirm('Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz ?')\">[SİL]</a> | 
            <a href=\"duzenle.php?id={$veri['id']}&duzenle=1\">DÜZENLE</a></th>

        </tr>";
        }
```

i want to get id's values from sayfa.php
duzenle.php

```
<?php
$baglan = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345') or die ('mysql sunucuya bağlanamadı.');
$veritabani_sec = mysql_select_db('vtben', $baglan);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$_POST=array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$_POST);
if(is_numeric($_GET[id]) && $_GET[duzenle]==1){
$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sayfalar WHERE id='$_GET[id]'");
$kayit = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu);
print_r($kayit);
echo <<<HTML
<h3>Sayfa Güncelleme</h3>
<form action="duzenle-guncelle.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$kayit[id]}">
<p><label for="isim">Başlık</label>
<input type="text" name="isim" value="{$kayit[isim]}"></p>
<p><label for="icerik">İçerik</label>
<textarea name="icerik" id="summernote"> {$kayit[icerik]}</textarea></p>
<p><label for="sira">Menü Sırası</label>
<input type="text" name="sira" value="{$kayit[sira]}"></p>
<p><label for="durum">Durumunu giriniz. Eğer 0 ise ust menude gözükür 1 ise üst menüde yer alamaz. Sadece rakam olarak 0 veya 1 değeri giriniz</label>
<input type="text" name="durum" value="{$kayit[durum]}"> </p>
<p><label for="seo_baslik">SEO Başlığı</label>
<input type="text" name="seo_baslik" value="{$kayit[seo_baslik]}"></p>
<p><label for="seo_aciklama">SEO Açıklama</label>
<input type="text" name="seo_aciklama" value="{$kayit[seo_aciklama]}"></p>
<br />
<p><input type="submit" value="Güncelle"></p>
</form>
HTML;
}
mysql_close($baglan);
?>
```

and then, i want to change values but not working
duzenle.guncelle.php

```
<?php
require_once('dbbaglan.php');
$id=$_POST["id"];
$isim=$_POST["isim"];
$icerik=$_POST["icerik"];
$sira=$_POST["sira"];
$durum=$_POST["durum"];
$seo_baslik=$_POST["seo_baslik"];
$seo_aciklama=$_POST["seo_aciklama"];

$guncelle=mysql_query("update yazilar SET isim='$isim',icerik='$icerik',
sira='$sira',durum='$durum',seo_baslik='$seo_baslik',seo_aciklama='$seo_aciklama' where id='$id'");

if($guncelle) {

echo "guncelleme basarili oldu<br />
<a href='yazilar.php'>geriye donerek islemlere devam edebilirsiniz</a>";
}else{
echo "guncelleme basarisiz oldu";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please use some clear explanation...

Comment: You are connecting to the db in your first file. Are you doing this in the second one, too?

Comment: @shail i dont konow english so much sorry

Comment: @colburton I use db connect file include both of them

Comment: Ranjith yes post error code

Comment: @hakkidilek : I'm asking you to update the `error` with your question

Comment: This is a hackers dream

Comment: 1. I know your username and password. 2. You're using a deprecated API, one that cannot make use of prepared statements.